# Import XCode project inside another XCode project

Tags: ios, xcode, import, dependencies

I imported an XCode project inside another XCode project. I dragged and dropped project B inside project A like in [How to Call Xcode Project In Another Xcode Project.......?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874273/how-to-call-xcode-project-in-another-xcode-project)

Next, i imported a class from project B in project A, so i could use a method but i gave me an error
      "ClassTemp.h' file not found".

From what i´ve read this should have worked. Do i have to do some kind of configuration for it to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding the location of your other project to the **Header Search Paths** in the **Build Settings** of the main project.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me,

In build **settings** --> **Header Search Path** --> Add below entry

`$(SRCROOT) and mark it as recursive.` 
 
 If above not worked you can also try following way, 
 
`<path-of-other-project> and mark it as recursive.` 
 Hope this helps to you ! **(You may require to clean or restart the workspace)**